# Shared Documents vs Documents

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm currently making an application that can access folders and files inside subsites. Folders and files are stored in either of these two - Shared Documents or Documents (according to its ServerRelativeUrl). How does SharePoint decide whether to keep folders and files inside Shared Documents or Documents? Is it related to the type of subsite that you're making?